# Efficient way to store orderbook in Python

Tags: python, large-data, large-files, quantitative-finance

I am using the Coinbase WebSocket API to extract real-time data about the orderbook for BTC-USD.

I am using the following code to store the snapshots of bids and asks and the changes to the orderbook everytime there is an update from the exchange.

```
import websocket,json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,timezone
from dateutil.parser import parse

pd.DataFrame(columns=['time','side','price','changes']).to_csv("changes.csv")
def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')
    
    subscribe_message ={
    "type": "subscribe",
    "channels": [
        {
            "name": "level2",
            "product_ids": [
                "BTC-USD"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
    print(subscribe_message)
    ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_message))

timeZero = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
timeClose = timeZero+timedelta(seconds=61)
def on_message(ws,message):
    js=json.loads(message)
    #print([js['time'],js['trade_id'],js['last_size'],js['best_ask'],js['best_bid']])
    if js['type']=='snapshot':
        print('Start: ',timeZero)
        pd.DataFrame(js['asks'],columns=['price','size']).to_csv("snapshot_asks.csv")
        pd.DataFrame(js['bids'],columns=['price','size']).to_csv("snapshot_bids.csv")
    elif js['type']=='l2update':
        mydate=parse(js['time'])
        if mydate >= timeClose:
            print('Closing at ', mydate)
            ws.close()
        side = js['changes'][0][0]
        price = js['changes'][0][1]
        change = js['changes'][0][2]
        pd.DataFrame([[js['time'],side, price, change]],columns=['time','side','price','changes']).to_csv("changes.csv",mode='a', header=False)
    
    
    
socket = "wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com"
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket,on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

In this way, all the changes are saved in a csv file. This code runs for approximately 1 minute, but I would like to make it run for one day and then reconstruct the orderbook.

Once this is done, I want to analyze the orderbook every second to study what is the price impact of buying (or selling) some specific amount bitcoins.

Of course, this code creates a very huge file 'changes.csv', and if I try to make it run on AWS, the CPU usage reaches 90% after some time and the process gets killed. What is the most efficient way to store the orderbook at every second?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about AWS, but one possible optimization is the storage.

For example, SQLite could be a good fit due to the flexible type system:

> [INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or
> 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Another advantage is its performance and simplicity: [Benefits of SQLite as a File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/aff_short.html)

---

Still, it's possible that your AWS settings won't let you analyze it cheaply (or for free?).

You can try with less data (just a day's worth, or whatever lets you analyze it) or less frequently (only get data every minute, hourly or daily).

Another option is to compress the file (to reduce AWS egress fees), download it, and analyze it locally. That way, only your hardware is the limit.